# Rendering a view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have partials calling from a bootstrap sidebar. Each tab points using bootstrap js to a partial. When I do an action and the page refreshes it brings me back to the default url courses/dashboad.

How can I put the div id into a parameter so that the redirect will stay on the partial view instead of going back to the default dashboard partial of the page please? So essentially want it to do

```
render 'courses/my_courses'
```

after the action is complete. Here is my view page and controller code. It's failing with a template missing error but i essentially want to redirect to the dashboard and then render this partial. Thanks lads.

Controller

```
def course_complete
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @course.update_attributes(complete: true)
    flash[:notice] = "Course name #{@course.title} now marked as complete"
    render 'courses/my_courses' 
end

def dashboard
    my_courses
    @company = @user.company
end
```

View

```
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="my_courses">
    <div class="dash-panel">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> My Courses</h3>
        <span>All your courses listed below</span>
    </div>
    <div class="courses-panel">
        <%= render 'courses/my_courses' %>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your question: You have a main page (i.e. `dashboard`) with multiple tabs, and you want to render a partial in the tab that is clicked but instead you are getting a redirection to your main page. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add redirect_to in your course_complete method and render partial in dashbaord method like this

```
def course_complete
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @course.update_attributes(complete: true)
    flash[:notice] = "Course name #{@course.title} now marked as complete"
    redirect_to your_dashboard_path
end

def dashboard
    my_courses
    render 'courses/my_courses' 
    @company = @user.company
end
```

Comment: Hi Code Runner, Not sure if I got my point across very well. It's hard to explain. So the default url for the my_courses page is courses_dashboard_path and that's fine but I have the actions all set to view in partial tabs from the sidebar. So essentially the view goes to the Dashboard page but what I need is for it then to click the tab and show the partial for that particular tab. 

So when I do an action say completed method I dont want the page refreshing back to the default view but to just refresh back to the tab section I am at.